# Error al utilizar Google Sign In en producción

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

Recientemente lancé mi app a producción en la Play Store y me da varios errores la autenticación vía Google. Utilizo la última versión de [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in).
Al lanzar mi aplicación a producción he actualizado mis claves sha-1 y sha-256 a las claves de producción. Sin embargo, la mitad de las veces que me intento autenticar por este método me devuelve el siguiente error:

> PlataformException(sign_in_failed, a6.b: 10: null,null)

[image: error]

Aquí es donde autentico al usuario:
**Llamada prinicipal:**

```
                try{
                   AuthProvider authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
                   await authProvider.signInWithGoogle();
                   Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'mainScreen');
                } on ClientIsOfflineException{
                    NotificationsService.showSnackbar("Revise su conexión a internet");
                }catch(e){
                    showDialog(context: context, builder: (_){
                        return AlertDialog(
                            content: Text(e.toString()),
                            );
                    });
                }
```

**authProvider.signInWithGoogle**

```
        try{
        // Trigger the authentication flow
        final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

        // Obtain the auth details from the request
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth = await googleUser?.authentication;

        // Create a new credential
        final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
          idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
        );

        // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
        return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
        }on PlatformException catch(e){
            if(e.code == "network_error"){
                throw ClientIsOfflineException();
            }else{
                rethrow;
            }
        }catch(e){
            rethrow;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta aquí:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56235#issuecomment-780841292

Lo que hay que hacer es ir a Play Store Console. A Configuración >> Integridad de la Aplicación
[image: Google Play Console]

y copiar las claves SHA-1 y SHA-256 con las que Play Store publica nuestra App. Las pegamos en la consola de firebase en la configuración del proyecto, agregándolas a nuestras claves SHA de producción